# bash process substitution + using same variable in main and sub-process

Tags: bash, race-condition, process-substitution

If I do

```
x=42
IFS= read -r x < <(echo "$x")
echo "$x"
```

am I guaranteed to get back 42, or is there a race condition like for reading from / writing to the same file in a pipeline (`cat /tmp/x | grep -v pat | cat >/tmp/x`)?

OK, for `read` it's kind of obvious, what about `mapfile` -- might it clear the destination (= source for subprocess) array before forking off the substituted process?

```
arr=( 'forty' 'two' )
mapfile -t arr < <(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}")
declare -p arr
```

*Edit*: maybe a better comparison would be to

```sh
{ echo 42; echo 13; } >/tmp/x
cat >/tmp/x < <(grep -v 13 /tmp/x)
cat /tmp/x
```

Answer (score 3):

> using same variable in main and sub-process

Each process has it's own space. They are separate variables.

> am I guaranteed to get back 42

Yes.

> might it clear the destination (= source for subprocess) array before forking off the substituted process?

No.

The subprocess `<(...)` has a **copy** of all the parent environment. It does not affect parent in any way.

Comment: It has a *copy* made **when** -- before or after `mapfile` might clear the array? When does the fork happen? That is the question

Comment: @usretc At least as I understand it, the parent shell has to create a pipe,  THEN fork the subshell running `echo "$x"`, THEN attach the other end of the pipe to an FD and substitute that (making something like `... < /dev/fd/63`, THEN run `read` (or `mapfile` or whatever) with that as its stdin. So I'm pretty sure the fork has to happen before the main command starts.

Comment: @GordonDavisson good summary. That's kind of what I thought but wanted to see some input